# AS3 Adding an image to class extending MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm new to AS3 but I've done some stuff with flash before. I have a class that extends MovieClip and has some properties and functions that I've defined. How do I associate an image with this class so that I can add objects of its type to the stage and see that image (along with being able to associate mouse events, etc.)? Here's the class:

```
public class Tank extends MovieClip {
    public var Id:int;
    public var HP:int;
    public var Dmg:int;

    public function Tank(id:int, hp:int, dmg:int){
        // constructor code
        this.Id = id;
        this.HP = hp;
        this.Dmg = dmg;

    }
}
```

Comment: By `Image` do you mean that you've imported a Bitmap or created some Vector graphics with the tools in Flash and converted it to a MovieClip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleanest way to do this would be to drop the `extends MovieClip` portion of your `Tank` and give it a property that will refer to its display.

```
public class Tank
{
    private var skin:Bitmap;

    public function Tank(...)
    {
        skin = new Bitmap( new YourImage() );
    }

    public function get Skin():Bitmap
    {
        return skin;
    }

}
```

`YourImage` would be replaced with the class name that you give to your Bitmap in the library if you go to `Properties -> ActionScript`:

[image]

This way when you create a `Tank`, you can add it to the `DisplayList` like this (from somewhere that you have access to the `stage`, like your document class or the timeline):

```
var tank:Tank = new Tank(...);
stage.addChild(tank.Skin);
```